# How can I correctly adjust the contrast of an image?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to change the contrast of an image from an horizonal slider in Qt. I used cv::saturate_cast to do that for brightness by converting the BGR to LAB and it worked. It doesn't seem to work for adjusting the contrast, I get black or light grey images, how can I fix it? This is what I've tried: (I got the formulas from https://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/  )

```
void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_2_valueChanged(int value)
{

    QPixmap pm =ui->label2->pixmap();

        if (!pm.isNull() )

   {
      for (int i=0; i < image.rows; i++)

        for (int j=0; j < image.cols; j++)

        {
            float factor = (259 * (value + 255)) / (255 * (259 - value));
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(  factor*(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]-128)+128);
              image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(  factor*(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]-128)+128);
                image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(  factor*(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]-128)+128);
        }

   
  QPixmap pm =MatToPixmap(image);
  QImage imageupdate= pm.toImage();


    int w = ui->label2->width();
    int h =ui-> label2->height();
  ui->label2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageupdate.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio)));
        }

}
```

Comment: the algorithm looks strange. HOW do you want to adjust the contrast?

Comment: by using the formula from the website above, where C is the value passed from the slider

Comment: can you try (float)image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[c]-(float)128 everywhere? currently your values will get over/underflows before the saturate_cast comes into play

Comment: good point, I tried and I can see a difference now but it seems like I still can't set the contrast to lower and then higher as I move the slider, it keeps staying grey/black, it should work if the value is negative right?

Comment: can you check the actual factor value? How does your input image look like? Is more bright or dark? I think best would be an input image with average intensity of 128

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was that all operations should be done on a copy of the original image